# How to extract multiple columns from a space delimited .DAT file in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm quite new to coding and don't have a proper education on the subject (most of my experience has been just stumbling through google searches) and I have a task that I would like assistance with.

I have 38 files which look something like this:

NGANo: 000a16d_1

Zeta: 0.050000

Ds5-95: 5.290000

Comments:

Period, SD, SV, SA

0.010000 0.000433 0.013167 170.812839
0.020000 0.001749 0.071471 172.720229
0.030000 0.004014 0.187542 176.055129
0.040000 0.007631 0.468785 189.322248
0.050000 0.012815 0.912067 203.359441
0.060000 0.019246 1.556853 210.602517
0.070000 0.025400 1.571091 206.360018

They're all .DAT files and are four columns of data (Period, SD, SV, SA) that are single space delimited in each row, additionally there are two spaces at the end of each line of data.

The only important data for me is the SA data, and I'd like to take the SA data and the title (this particular example being 000a16d_1) from each of these 38 files and put them all on the same sheet of an excel spreadsheet (one column after the next) with just the title followed by the SA data.

I've tried a few different things, but I'm stuck on how to separate the rows of data from one column into 4.  I'm not too knowledgeable on whether I should use numpy or pandas.  I know that everything up to the second to last line is correct, as when I have print(table) it does print the rows of data, I just don't understand how to separate the single column into multiple.  Here is my current code, all assistance is appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import xlsxwriter
#
path = "C:/Users/amihi/Downloads/Plotter_Output"
dirs = os.listdir(path)
#
#
for file in dirs:
    table = pd.read_table(file, skiprows=4)
    SA = table.loc[:,"SA"]
    print(SA)
```

Comment: Like skiprows, there's another parameter called `usecols`. Use it to choose the columns you're interested in. And perhaps you have to set `delimiter` to '\s' for spaces explicitly.

Comment: `table = pd.read_table(file, skiprows=4, sep='\s+', usecols='SA')`?

Comment: @AmiTavory when I tried running that line it spit out the following error:   
ValueError: Passed header names mismatches usecols

Comment: @AmedeoH Right, typo. `table = pd.read_table(file, skiprows=4, sep='\s+', usecols=['SA'])`.

Comment: Even still, its giving the following errors: raise ValueError("Usecols do not match names.")
ValueError: Usecols do not match names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also do this without using pandas if you wanted. The code below will deal only with the table section of it, but wont deal with the info at the top of the file.

```
finalColumns = []
for file in dirs:
    with open(file, "r") as f:
        for l in f:
            line = l.strip("\n")
            splitted = line.split()
            if len(splitted) > len(columns):
                 for i in range(len(splitted)):
                     columns.append([])
            counter = 0
            for item in splitted:
                columns[counter].append(item)
                counter += 1   
        finalColumns.append(columns[3])
```

When adding to your other file, simply loop through finalColumns and each item will be what should be a new column in your file.

Comment: So then using this code, columns[3] gets me the SA data in a list form thats comma delimited, can I then use xlsxwriter to take this list and turn it into a column in excel?

Comment: columns[3] should be the SA data in a python list form. If you want it to be structured like "item1,item2,item3,item4", you can use ",".join(columns[3])

Comment: @Amedeo H let me know if it works for you or if you need more help with it.

Comment: so the columns works well, and I can export the SA data to individual excel files no problem, however when I try to export them to the same excel file it does something weird.  I have within the "for file in dirs" loop 3 lines that are as follows:

Comment: export = pd.DataFrame(columns[3]) #---next line---
    export.to_excel("Try.xlsx", index=False, header=False, startcol=x1, startrow=0) #---next line---
    x1 += 1

Comment: my intention with this was to get each line of data from the DAT files on a different column, while this does get all of the data from all 38 of the DAT files into the excel document, they're all stacked on the 38th column of the excel file in a column thats 152000 cells long (38DAT files at 4000 entries per each)

Comment: Right. I see my mistake now. If you'll give me a second, I can fix that.If it works for you now, feel free to accept it as your answer.